# Required item type of the context item for the child axis is node(); supplied value (.) has item type xs:anyAtomicType

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

Here is my code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(m/@x)">
  <xsl:variable name="x" select="."/>
  <xsl:value-of select="count(m[@x = $x])"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Saxon says something along these lines:

```
Static error at char .. in xsl:for-each/@select on line .. column .. of main.xsl:
  XPTY0020: Required item type of the context item for 
  the child axis is node(); supplied value (.) has item 
  type xs:anyAtomicType
```

What's wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you should use is e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="m" group-by="@x">
  <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

If you want to go along with that distinct-values attempt then store e.g. `<xsl:variable name="context-node" select="."/>` before the `for-each` and inside access `<xsl:value-of select="count($context-node/m[@x = $x])"/>` or `<xsl:value-of select="count($context-node/m[@x = current()])"/>`

Answer (score 2):

To add to Martin's answer, what's wrong is that in the expression `count(m[@x = $x])`, `m` means `./child::m`, that is, you're asking for element children of the context item that are named `m`; but the containing `xsl:for-each` changes the context item so it is a string (one of the distinct values), which of course has no children.